# No output for this code

Tags: c++

I don't know why this program is not printing anything, not even the first print statement. What can be the problem?

It compiles successfully using `g++ filename.cpp`.

```
#include "deck.h"
#include "hand.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "not even this";

    vector<Hand> hands;
    Deck deck;
    int players; 
    int seed;
    int sizeOfHand = 5;
    int i;
    vector<Hand>::iterator itr;

    cout << "Enter seed: ";
    cin >> seed;
    srand(unsigned(seed));

    cout << "Enter number of players: ";
    cin >> players; 

    for (i = 0; i < players; i++) {
        hands.push_back(Hand());
    }

    deck.Shuffle();
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfHand; i++) {
        vector<Card> cards = deck.Deal(players);
        for (itr = hands.begin(); itr < hands.end(); itr++) {
            cout << "1";
            itr->add(*cards.begin());
            cards.erase(cards.begin());    
        }
    }

    for (itr = hands.begin(), i=1; itr < hands.end(); itr++, i++) {
        cout << "Player " + i;
        itr->showHand();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Most operating systems buffer the output you write to `cout` (or `cerr`) for performance reasons. Unless you flush the output (which happens for example if you also print line breaks), you only see the output as soon as the cache is full and flushed to the standard output, and thus becomes visible in the console window. This buffer can hold quite a lot of characters; probably everything your program outputs. This behavior is called "line-buffered".

There are two ways to fix your program, depending on what you *actually* want to have:

1. One solution is to output a line-break in your code every time you want the output to become visible:

   ```
   cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
   ```

   The line-break is not printed automatically because one might want to write something *without* a line break afterwards, e.g. when the logic to produce a line of output is split into several lines of code, or if the output is of some binary nature.
2. To flush the output *without* writing line-breaks, you have again two options:

   - call [`cout.flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) after printing

     ```
     cout << "Enter a number: ";
     cout.flush();
     ```
   - stream [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) into `cout`, which can be combined with the printing code:

     ```
     cout << "Enter a number: " << flush;
     ```

Comment: shouldn't it be possible to wait for input in the same line?

Comment: Yes, I guess the `cin` statements work anyways and the program *itself* runs as expected. You can't really tell if you don't see any output ;) (You could debug it to be sure though)

Comment: @A4L Ah I misunderstood your question. For this, see paddy's answer.

Comment: hmmm.. this seems to be platform dependent, just tested a basic I/O  without flush and it works (win7 32 + g++ (GCC) 4.6.2) :/

Comment: @A4L On which OS? I never worked on an OS which doesn't cache the stdout stream...

Comment: On some platforms, reading input from `stdin` will flush `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is already answered, in terms of what is happening, but line breaks aren't the only solution.

If you want input on the same line as the output, you can flush:

```
cout << "Enter seed: " << flush;
cin >> seed;
```

Note that `endl` actually invokes a `flush` internally.  It's different from just writing `"\n"`.

Comment: Hm, I thought writing `"\n"` also flushes. Does this only count for `printf`? If I remember correctly, `cout` is *not* implemented in terms of `printf` so this might be the reason why they behave differently here?

Comment: `"\n"` will only flush if the stream is line buffered.  By default, streams tied to interactive devices (like the console) are line buffered.  However, the purpose of `endl` is to write a newline and *always* flush.  For fully buffered streams you will see a difference between using `endl` and `"\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable continuous buffering for your stream. Add this at the top of `main`:

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```

This causes the stream to flush after each output operation.